# Mistakenly Killed the sqlserver.exe process in task manager, how to restart it?

Tags: sql-server

I mistakenly killed the `sqlserver.exe` process in `Task Manager > Process > (show processes by all users) > sqlserver.exe`

Now my database is not connecting, Management Studio and all applications shows this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Even in the configuration manager, the services are not showing up.. Kindly help as I need to get access to it. Data in this instance is very important..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by:

> **To start the default instance of SQL Server**
>
> On the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2008 R2, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL
>   Server Configuration Manager.
>
> In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, click SQL
>   Server Services.
>
> In the details pane, right-click SQL Server (MSSQLServer), and then
>   click Start.  A green arrow on the icon next to the server name and on
>   the toolbar indicates that the server started successfully.
>
> Click OK to close SQL Server Configuration Manager.
>
> **To start a named instance of SQL Server**
>
> On the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2008 R2, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL
>   Server Configuration Manager.
>
> In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, click SQL
>   Server.
>
> In the details pane, right-click the named instance of SQL Server, and
>   then click Start. A green arrow on the icon next to the server name
>   and on the toolbar indicates that the server started successfully.
>
> Click OK to close SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Or you can reboot the server, assuming you have the services set to auto start.

Or you can go into the services view type Services and right click on the SQLServer service and hit restart

[**More information here**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190699%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Open the services window, start--> run --> services.msc. There you can find all the SQLserver related services starting with SQL.

The process you killed can be started by starting the `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` service.

You can start a service by right-click --> start

Answer (score 0):

powershell to start the default instance:

```
start-service mssqlserver;
```

If you have a named instance, do a `get-service *sql*` first to determine the name of the service. Note: you'll probably need to enclose the name in single quotes as it is likely to contain a dollar sign.